# selector for title results in undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/f69tc7xj/)

```
<span class="ownername" id="fname" data-class="ownername" title="072-219-461-000">
Consuelo Delos Reyes Gonzales ,
</span>
```

Getting the title of this span using

```
$('#af_rpta_listoflandref_mchns').find("tr:not(:eq(0))");
var $tds = $(this).find('td');

alert($tds.eq(2).find('span.ownername').find('#fname').attr('title'));
```

Rresults in `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

```
var $trs = $('#af_rpta_listoflandref_mchns').find("tr").eq(1);
var $span = $($trs).find('td > span.ownername');

alert($span.attr('title'));
```

Comment: Well it depends on the previous selected DOM, which appears to be a table not included in your question. Edit: I see your fiddle, give me a minute.

Comment: it is included in the fiddle the entire table is there

Comment: try this, without seeing multiple sets of data, it is hard to tell what the dynamic portion of this might, be, you might try looping over it.

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/f69tc7xj/1/)

```
var $rows1 = $('#af_rpta_listoflandref_mchns').find("tr:not(:eq(0))");

$rows1.each(function () {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td');
    alert($tds.eq(2).find("span#fname.ownername").data('id'));
});
```

Iterate through the table. Also i change the title to data attr named it id

Answer (score 0):

An `id` should be unique in your document. So in this case `$('#fname').attr('title')` would give you the title you need.

But based on your comment on Amey Deshpandes answer I'm guessing that there will be more rows, with more span.

So you got two option:

- change the `id` to a `class`
- give the elements an unique `id` (for example `id="fname1"`).

From that point you also need to adapt your selectors to it:

```
/* with class*/
$('.fname').each( function() {
   var title = $(this).attr('title');
   alert( title );
});

/* with id + counter */
$('[id^=fname]').each( function() {
   var title = $(this).attr('title');
   alert( title );
});

/* based on it's position */
$('#af_rpta_listoflandref_mchns tbody tr:not(:first)').each( function() {
    var title = $(this).find('td:nth-child(3) span').attr('title');
    alert( title );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
$("tr").each(function() {

    v = $(this).find("td:nth-child(3) span.ownername").attr("title"); 

});

alert(v);
```

Comment: ateast supply an explanation and proper format for code